# How to animate, while switching though objects

Tags: animation

In Mario Odyssey, The characters eye's are too difficult of a shape to do regular eyeball topology. So they rely on a plane that is Iris/Pupil like. But sense The eyeball can't be rigged, sense the eye's are a oblong shape. They use a verity of other object's to do the blinking. But my question is how does one animate such a complex eye. I'm referencing this Luigi model from Mario Odyssey. [Nintendo Switch - Super Mario Odyssey - Luigi](https://www.models-resource.com/nintendo_switch/supermarioodyssey/model/24104/) I have all the eye object's for blinking. but I don't know how to set this up for animation.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please add [reference images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post) to your post to help others understand what you wish to achieve

Comment: I guess you have 2 solutions, either use UV Warp modifier to stick pictures that you can animate on the surface: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5NlvgMYZgaY  /    https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kB9cJ3wOoPk  or use sphere that you squeeze with Lattice: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1MfxTdq0V2I